# Accessing datetime-local value does not work. Can't figure out why

Tags: javascript, html, datetime, dom

**EDIT**:

So, after more playing the problem is a bit more complex than originally thought, and while I have found a workaround, I'm curious to figure out why this is happening, so here's the update:

I have created the following function to fill in form fields using HTML DOM:

```
function populateField(fieldname, value) {
        document.getElementById(fieldname).value = value;
    }
```

Then in the main part of my php code, I call that function and hand it the ID of the field, and the VALUE I want to set like this:

```
echo('<script>');
echo('populateField("contact", "'.$fillContact.'");');
echo('</script>');
```

This works perfectly fine for all my form fields *except* for the datetime-local field. It simply doesn't work.

So I decided to bypass my function, and just set the field directly in the main part of the code like this:

```
echo('document.getElementById("arrival").value = "'.$fillArrive.'";');
```

This works perfectly fine...but ONLY if I execute it *before* I call my function for the first time.  In other words...

THIS works:

```
echo('<script>');
echo('document.getElementById("arrival").value = "'.$fillArrive.'";');
echo('populateField("contact", "'.$fillContact.'");');
echo('</script>');
```

but THIS does not work:

```
echo('<script>');
echo('populateField("contact", "'.$fillContact.'");');
echo('document.getElementById("arrival").value = "'.$fillArrive.'";');
echo('</script>');
```

For the life of me I can't figure out why it would make any difference at all, but there you have it. If anyone sees something that I'm missing, I would love to know what I'm doing wrong!

Thanks all!

**ORIGINAL**:

So this is an interesting one.  I have an HTML form field with multiple fields, including a datetime-local field.  Using Javascript I am able to access and/or change the value property of all of the other input fields using HTML DOM, but for some reason, I am unable to access or set the datetime-local value property.  Trying to read the value of the field returns a value of "" and trying to set the value has no effect.

Interestingly, if I include the value="some datetime" into the HTML tag itself, it sets the value property correctly. Thinking the value="" may have been somehow mucking things up, I removed it, but there is no difference.

Here is the field code within the form:

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="arrival" id="arrival" value="'.date('Y-m-d').'T00:00">
```

That works correctly and sets the field to the current date with a time of 00:00:00.000.

But if I do something like this afterwords:

```
x = document.getElementById("arrival").value;
```

Then x = "";

Likewise, if I attempt to set the field by doing this:

```
document.getElementById("arrival").value = [some datetime value];
```

the field remains blank.

Obviously, I'm missing something here, but for the life of me I can't figure out what.  I even went to lookup an example.  This example works fine, but even copying the lines it still doesn't work in my code:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_datetime-local_value

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid your value for date is not in correct format. You need to have ISO-8601 formated date as mozilla references it in online docs here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local

```
var dateControl = document.querySelector('input[type="datetime-local"]');
dateControl.value = '2017-06-01T08:30';
```

Also, if you not set value and try to console it, it's empty as expected, and after you set it, it yields same date in ISO format.

GL

```js
function myFunction() {
  console.log( document.getElementById("myLocalDate").value )
}
```

```html
Date: <input type="datetime-local" id="myLocalDate" value="">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Console date</button>
```

Comment: Ok... so it turns out, it's not the string formatting at all.  It has something to do with a function I've written.  If I set the datetime-local field *before* I call my javascript function, it works perfectly fine.  However, if I try to set the datetime-local field *after* I call my function, it doesn't work at all.... I'll update the above question.  I have a workaround (set the field first) but would love to figure out why...